# How to remap eject key on MacBook keyboard to "delete"?

Tags: macos, keyboard, remapping, eject, macbook

I own a first generation MacBook Air and this has bothered me since the beginnings.

When I bought this thing, I was sure I'm not going to carry a DVD drive. I don't use it. WiFi has worked pretty well for me so far and in fact, lack of optical drive was the least problem I had with it (the worst was the heat and CPU frequency reduction).

But there's a useless eject key right in a place suited for a great **delete** key (the real delete, in PC terminology, of course). It'll help a lot when you're developing in Xcode. I feel it's handled at a lower level than standard keyboard shortcuts. Is there any way to remap it to delete?

Comment: The *real delete* is called *forward delete* on a Mac. But that doesn't help you of course. ;-)

Comment: @Arjan, Mac is screwed up when it comes to productivity.

Answer (score 7):

Not related to remapping, but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd> will do a forward delete in most OS X text fields.

Comment: Ack, I wouldn't want to get into the habit of typing <kbd>ctrl D</kbd> or I'd type it at the command line...

Comment: does forward delete on command line too. It doesn't send EOF unless you're at the end of the line.

Comment: this is saviour, `fn`+`delete` is always stressful for hands

Answer (score 4):

I have no experience with the application myself, but perhaps [DoubleCommand](http://doublecommand.sourceforge.net/) can help you?

#### Update

According to their website, [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://www.pqrs.org/tekezo/macosx/keyremap4macbook/document.html) should be able to map the Eject button to a forward delete.

[This MacRumors forum](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=408363) also has a thread on the same subject.

Comment: It doesn't support eject key.

Comment: You may be able to edit the source so it does: I use a custom version of DoubleCommand that maps Caps Lock to Escape, for instance.

Comment: KeyRemap4MacBook (together with NoEjectDelay) works but the problem is, you can't hold eject to delete a long string. It just removes a single character each time.

Answer (score 2):

I also dislike using *fn* for any key, so I basically stopped using Forward Delete altogether. When I need the Forward Delete I often hold down Shift and use the cursor keys to make a selection, and then press Delete. Actually, I do this for every text I want to delete -- those cursor keys go into all directions. :-)

Comment: Wow, apparently I down-voted this, but I have no recollection of doing so. And now it's too late to undo it. Sorry :(

Comment: You don't have to shift select. Just do rightkey and delete. For multiple chars, its faster to fly to the location using win/opt arrow and then followed by win/opt delete. Shift key is annoying.

Answer (score 2):

Karabiner (which replaced KeyRemap4MacBook) does provide a means to remap the Eject key.  Just tested it with El Capitan GM, and it works fine.

Comment: And like karabiner says: the eject key has a delay. Use [NoEjectDelay](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/noejectdelay.html) to get rid of the delay.

Comment: I don't find the eject key in the simple modification list